# Error 500 in laravel 5.2: session store not set on request

Tags: laravel-5

I was run `composer update` and `composer self-update` in laravel project
now
I get error 500 and blank white page after user login and see project pages
this picture is my log

Error message: `session store not set on request`

laravel log

Laravel version is 5.2

[image: 1]

I run this command

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear 
composer install
composer dump-autoload
```

anybody can help me?
kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\langcheck::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\B2b::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

...
```

The kernel.php (in App\Http) is most likely the reason for this error

Comment: Open app/http/kernel.php and copy/paste it here in code block (```)

Comment: can you tell me more

Comment: Try this step first, there's not much else to tell: Open app/http/kernel.php and copy/paste it here. There is a file called 'kernel.php'. Find it in your Laravel installation. Open that file. Copy the contents. Paste it in your original question

Comment: ok i'm paste the content

Answer (score -1):

So first of all... Your Laravel is really really old.
Next: you need to change the `app/Http/Kernel.php` (the file you pasted)
There are some classes which are in your `$middlewareGroups` and you need to move them over to `$middleware`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    StartSession::class,
    ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11494#issuecomment-167003230

But just prepare, that you need to upgrade. Your example files are here:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.3, etc.
The upgrade instructions are here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#main-content

Keep your PHP version in mind. It might still be PHP 7, so you cannot go further than Laravel version 8.

Happy upgrading!